# Perl XML::LibXML getting the Nth element

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

Here is some simplified sample xml

```
<book_reviewers>
    <results>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Anne</name>
            <profession>Catfish wrangler</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Bob</name>
            <profession>Beer taster</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Charlie</name>
            <profession>Gardener</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Don</name>
            <profession>DoGooder</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Ellie</name>
            <profession>Elephant Trainer</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Freddy</name>
            <profession>Fencer</profession>
        </reviewer>
    </results>
</book_reviewers>
```

Them i parse the data

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::LibXML;
use strict;

my $filename = "cr.xml";

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $critic_details = $parser->parse_file("$filename") or die;
```

Now I want to grab the details of a random reviewer

```
my $no_of_critics = ($critic_details->findvalue("count(/book_reviewers/results/reviewer)"));
```

I send number 1 and $no_of_critics off to a subroutine that returns a random number between one and $no_of_critics (i.e. n this case 1 and 6)

All of this works fine I just need to know how I tell it which reviewer - say it returns 5, then how do I tell it I want the fifth occurrence of reviewer? I have tried searching but I cannot get the right search term so I am a bit stuck

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on top of what yu already had in your previous question:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;

use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = "cr.xml";

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $critic_details = $parser->parse_file("$filename") or die;

# find ALL the <book_reviewers><results><reviewers> nodes
my @reviewers = $critic_details
  ->findnodes("book_reviewers/results/reviewer");
die "no reviewer nodes in xml-file" unless @reviewers;

# @reviewers in scalar context gives the number of elements
my $reviewer = $reviewers[ rand @reviewers ];

printf "reviewer: %s (%s)\n",
  $reviewer->findvalue("name"),
  $reviewer->findvalue("profession"),
  ;

__END__
```

which could result in:

```
reviewer: Anne (Catfish wrangler)
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you get 5 in return, then what you need to do is iterate over nodes and keep a counter which increments at each iteration, if the counter reaches 5, then you can print out information of that node.

Check `findnodes` at [**XML::LibXML::Node**](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod).

Also see:

1. [perl script to iterate over xml nodes using XML::LibXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140440/perl-script-to-iterate-over-xml-nodes-using-xmllibxml)
2. [Iterating over nodes using XML::LibXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894789/iterating-over-nodes-using-xmllibxml)

Answer (score 0):

`findnodes` returns an array.  You simply need to select which index of that array you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);

my @reviewers = $dom->findnodes('//reviewer');
print "Count = " . @reviewers . "\n";

my $i = int rand @reviewers;
my $record = $reviewers[$i];
print $record, "\n";

__DATA__
<book_reviewers>
    <results>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Anne</name>
            <profession>Catfish wrangler</profession>
        </reviewer>
...
```

Comment: All great answers, thanks  -starting to get my head around it all

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath expression that specifies n-th element in a list:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = 'cr.xml';

my $parser         = 'XML::LibXML'->new();
my $critic_details = $parser->parse_file($filename) or die;
my $index          = 1 + int rand $critic_details->findvalue('count(/book_reviewers/results/reviewer)');
my $reviewer       = $critic_details->findnodes("/book_reviewers/results/reviewer[$index]");
print $reviewer;
```

Note that positions in XPath start from 1, unlike from 0 as array indices in Perl.